# Does the economics behind exchanges allow to profit from crypto exchange rates?

Tags: exchange-rate

Say we have TheBestCryptoMarketSiteEver.com

```
I have $1000.
I buy BTC with those
I buy ETH with the BTC
I buy LTC with the ETH
I buy USD With the LTC
```

There's a fee for each of those transaction 0.1% - 0.5% depending.

Would an exchange site's rates ever vary enough to allow for profit from the above gymnastics?
Would it be possible to ever end up with more USD than I started with ?

Comment: Depends on the timeframe you're talking about, but generally, yes.

Comment: @RutgerVersteegden Can you expand on what you mean by time-frame, what' might be more preferable option